# Вывод ошибки в консоли при подключении внешнего скрипта

Tags: javascript

Почему не видит внешний скрипт? Пишет в консоли:

> file:///C:/Users/%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/Desktop/JavaScr…D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F!/test/alert.js
>   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Код:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>

<script>
    alert( 'Я - JavaScript!' );
  </script>
<script src="alert.js"></<script>

</body>
</html>
```

В задании указано внести внешний скрип в одной директории с обычным  скриптом и убедится что сообщение по прежнему выводится.

Если обычный скрипт будете в хедере, то все нормально кроме ошибки с внешним скриптом, а если в будут вместе, то кроме ошибки ничего не выводит.

Comment: Не закрыт тег скрипт, закрыть правильно. Вместо `</<script>` нужно `</script>`

Comment: Попробуйте скопировать проэкт на диск c:\ или d:\ так что б путь не содержал "пробел". В некоторых случаях пробел становится помехой. Попробуйте вместо длинного имени папки указать короткое (с тильдой).